# How can I convert similarly named POST variables into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm trying to accept an unknown number of similarly named POST variables like the following:

```
foo[bar[0]] = 56
foo[bar[1]] = 43
foo[bar[2]] = ah84
foo[bar[3]] = 92hs
```

With the rest of my POST data looking like:

```
foo[baz] = 1432
foo[expected] = 48hf
```

Some requests may have no foobars, but most will have 1, and some with have 2-4.

Ideally I would like to end with an array: `array( 56, 43, ah84, 92hs)`

Is there a way to loop through the POST variables not knowing the number of them? I can create the array if I know what to expect, but in this case I have no way of telling what will come across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at [this example](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#96902) might be a bit of help.

If you know you have an array (with non-sequential indices) and you don't care about the order, the cheapest and easiest fix would be `array_values`.

In your case, it'd be something like `$some_var = array_values($_POST['foo']['bar'])`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
$vars = array_unique($your_post_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the request header and get the post info from it.

```
<?php
$header = getallheaders();
$postInfo = explode("&", $header[count($header) - 1]);
for($i = 0; $i < count($postInfo); $i++)
{
$a = explode("=", $postInfo[$i]);
$postInfo[$i] = $a[1];
}
?>
```

Not tested & may not work but I think you'll get the idea.